# Getting `Error:Cannot get property ':lib' on null object` on a new Android Studio project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I've created a new project with Android Studio and added new lib project inside, but now I'm getting this:

`Error:Cannot get property ':lib' on null object`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Apparently I managed to solve it by adding comma in `settings.gradle` file.

Before I had:

`include ':app' ':lib'`

Changed to:

`include ':app', ':lib'`

Note, the comma!

Error messages could be better :)

Comment: Thanks.  As you said the error message could have been better.

Comment: The kind of stuff that pays for stackoverflow on it's own. Plus it's free. Thanks

Comment: My build.gradle differs somehow: 
    `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) `  what should i do?

Comment: @MortezaRastgoo, take a look to `settings.gradle` file instead of `build.gradle`. My problem was in `settings.gradle` file.