# Error:Execution failed for task ':agendacalendar:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Compilation failed;

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, java-8, android-gradle-plugin

I pickedup a project from Github and try to run in my Android Studio (2.1.3) but  it pops me an error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':agendacalendarview:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.  Compilation failed;
>   see the compiler error output for details.

I am using Java 1.8, Build tools version - "24.0.3", compileSdkVersion - 24.

I had tried so many related solutions from StackOverFlow and other sources, but unfortunately no solution worked for me.

Here i'm attaching my Gradle files,

## **Build.gradle (Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.efftronics.android.samplecustomcalendar"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    //avoid duplicate files during packaging of APK
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }

}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'

    // Other libraries
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.0'
    compile project(':agendacalendar')
}
```

## **Build.gradle (Module:agendacalendar)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    android {
        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    // Google libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'

    // other libraries
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.1'
}
```

## **Build.gradle (Project : SampleCustomCalendar)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {

    //--> To Avoid JavaC Compilation Errors
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        configure(options) {
            incremental = true
        }
    }

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

## **Entire Log :**

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :agendacalendar:generateDebugSources, :agendacalendar:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :agendacalendar:mockableAndroidJar, :agendacalendar:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :agendacalendar:compileDebugSources, :agendacalendar:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :agendacalendar:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources]
Observed package id 'build-tools;20.0.0' in inconsistent location 'C:\Android\Android_SDK\build-tools\android-4.4W' (Expected 'C:\Android\Android_SDK\build-tools\20.0.0')
Jack is required to support java 8 language features.
Jack is required to support java 8 language features.
:clean
:agendacalendar:clean
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar
:agendacalendar:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:agendacalendar:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:agendacalendar:checkDebugManifest
:agendacalendar:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:agendacalendar:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:agendacalendar:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:agendacalendar:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:agendacalendar:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2400Library
:agendacalendar:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72400Library
:agendacalendar:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2400Library
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:agendacalendar:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72400Library
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugAndroidTestJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugUnitTestJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugUnitTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:agendacalendar:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Library
:agendacalendar:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2400Library
:agendacalendar:prepareSeEmilsjolanderStickylistheaders270Library
:agendacalendar:prepareDebugDependencies
:agendacalendar:compileDebugAidl
:agendacalendar:compileDebugRenderscript
:agendacalendar:generateDebugBuildConfig
:agendacalendar:mergeDebugShaders
:agendacalendar:compileDebugShaders
:agendacalendar:generateDebugAssets
:agendacalendar:mergeDebugAssets
:agendacalendar:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:agendacalendar:generateDebugResources
:agendacalendar:mergeDebugResources
:agendacalendar:processDebugManifest
:agendacalendar:processDebugResources
:agendacalendar:generateDebugSources
:agendacalendar:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:agendacalendar:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:agendacalendar:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:agendacalendar:compileLint
:agendacalendar:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:agendacalendar:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:agendacalendar:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:agendacalendar:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_92). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for java.lang.invoke.MethodType not found
:agendacalendar:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':agendacalendar:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 48.612 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you "see the compiler error output for details"?

Comment: I hope u r already tried this delete your app's build folder  and re-build and try once?

Comment: @Raghavendra thanks for your reply but still facing the same Issue.

Comment: @ShamiliRani can u post your entire error log?

Comment: @Raghavendra,  Attached Entire Log in Post

Comment: @ShamiliRani I read it somewhere can u swap apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda' these 2 and try to build again

Comment: @ShamiliRani in project structure check the jdk pointed to java 8 location or not?

Comment: @Raghavendra , Swapped plugins and Re-build --> Not Solved Issue, Removed build folder in structure and Re-build --> Still Not Solved.

Comment: @Raghavendra, Yes SDK pointing to Java 8

Comment: @ShamiliRani can u try these statements? apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

retrolambda {
    jdk System.getenv("JAVA8_HOME")
    oldJdk System.getenv("JAVA7_HOME")
    javaVersion JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

Comment: @ShamiliRani can u post your gradle file after adding these lines.?

Comment: @ShamiliRani as Ironman said include  jackOptions {
      enabled true
    } inside defaultConfig block of app module's gradle

Comment: @Raghavendra 

apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

added that piece of code in **Build.gradle**

android { 
......  

retrolambda { jdk System.getenv("JAVA8_HOME") oldJdk System.getenv("JAVA7_HOME") javaVersion JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7 } 

}

dependecies{

 .....

}

Still getting same Error

Answer (score 0):

As I notice you are using `Java 8 language features requires Jack enabled`, you need to add the following to your gradle file (as shown above):

```
jackOptions {
    enabled true
}
```

so you have to add this in your `build.gradle` file. and then try `clean` and `rebuild` the project.

Comment: Hi.. thanks for your response. Still issue is not cleared. After enabling JackOptions ,i'm getting "Error:Cannot get property 'destinationDir' on null object"

Comment: @ShamiliRani can you post `settings.gradle` file ?

Comment: @ShamiliRani you can also visit this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441204/getting-errorcannot-get-property-lib-on-null-object-on-a-new-android-studi

Comment: Settings.gradle

include ':app', ':agendacalendar'